# PSQLException: ERROR: column "classification" is of type classification but expression is of type character varying

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I have the following JPA repo with insert query method:

```
public interface CMRepository extends JpaRepository <CMark, String> {

@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO c_mark(class_fk, s_con_fk, dis_con_fk, rto_fk, version, classification) " +
        "values(:class_fk, :s_con_fk, :dis_con_fk, :rto_fk, :version, :classification)", nativeQuery = true)
int insertCMark(@Param("class_fk") String class_fk, @Param("s_con_fk") String s_con_fk, @Param("dis_con_fk") String dis_con_fk,
                        @Param("rto_fk") String rto_fk, @Param("version") int version, @Param("classification") String classification);
}
```

When executed, I get the following error:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: column "classification" is of type classification but expression is of type character varying
```

The database has that field defined as USER-DEFINED. I believe from similar posts I am supposed to cast the classification field? If so, I am not sure how to do it. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, figured this out. I had to cast like this:

```
public interface CMRepository extends JpaRepository <CMark, String> {

@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO c_mark(class_fk, s_con_fk, dis_con_fk, rto_fk, version, classification) " +
    "values(:class_fk, :s_con_fk, :dis_con_fk, :rto_fk, :version, :classification\\:\\:classification)", nativeQuery = true)
int insertCMark(@Param("class_fk") String class_fk, @Param("s_con_fk") String s_con_fk, @Param("dis_con_fk") String dis_con_fk,
                    @Param("rto_fk") String rto_fk, @Param("version") int version, @Param("classification") String classification);
}
```

(notice the required escapes)